# How to install Internet Explorer 7 In windows 7

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer

I need that because I use a web program that only works fine with internet explorer 7.

neither Firefox 3.5, neither Google Chrome works fine.

Or if you know other explorer with full compatibility that could be the answer.

Comment: Why can't you use Inter Explorer 8, included with Windows 7? Or do you have one of the 'European' Windows 7s, without a default browser? In that case, you can probably find IE7 on the microsoft download site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried IE 8 in full IE 7 Compatibility mode?

You can try just clicking the broken paper icon in the URL bar at the top (will put you in Compatibility mode) or do a full IE 7 Browser mode if that doesn't work:

With IE 8, open the Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd>, and make sure you set "Internet Explorer 7" as your Browser Mode and "Internet Explorer Standards" as your Document Mode. If this works, you can modify your compatibility view settings to always run the specific website in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 5):

If IE7 compatibility mode does not work, you could try using [spoon's browser sandbox](http://spoon.net/browsers/).

Answer (score 4):

If you have an edition of Windows which is licensed to use Windows 7's "XP Mode" then you can use that feature to [create a VM and install IE7](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/). Else you can use a VM software like VirtualBox, VMWare etc to create a VM and install Windows XP & IE7.

Comment: Pretty sure the default XP VM that comes with XP Mode has IE7 in it? If not XP or Vista+IE7 VHDs can be downloaded from Microsoft for testing purposes (but will time out after a certain date) - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Comment: XP Mode in Windows 7 comes with IE6, not IE7. Of course it can still be updated as needed.